# Why can I boot and install windows from a MS MDT server, using ISC for the dhcp server, but only under lageacy bios, not UEFI?

Tags: linux, dhcp, mdt

Setup is:

Windows 2012 R2 with MDT 2013
Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 running ISC dhcp
Client can be VM/Hardware doesn't matter.

If I stay in legacy bios mode things work splendidly. When I switch to UEFI, and watch the log on the DHCP server, I see DCHPDISCOVE, and DHCPOFFER, but no ACK. Client never accepts the offer, and doesn't get an IP.

I have been all over Google trying option after option, no dice.

/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.con is very basic. I have a subnet and a range set, as well as routers, and dns.

Comment: Hmmm, I have never tried that. Let me test it and get back to you.

Comment: I just UEFI secure booted my 2nd Gen Hyper-V VM using ISC DHCPd, Samba DNS and MS WDS... The boot image was Windows 8.1 Update 1 x64.

This did not work for a 64bit Windows 7 image because it did not support secure boot...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my DHCPd config file, hopefully it sheds information upon your issue because my setup is working. I have removed my MAC addresses for privacy reasons. If your setup is similiar to mine then you might be having client issues...

```
#
# Sample configuration file for ISC dhcpd for Debian
#
# Attention: If /etc/ltsp/dhcpd.conf exists, that will be used as
# configuration file instead of this file.
#
#

# The ddns-updates-style parameter controls whether or not the server will
# attempt to do a DNS update when a lease is confirmed. We default to the
# behavior of the version 2 packages ('none', since DHCP v2 didn't
# have support for DDNS.)
ddns-update-style none;

# option definitions common to all supported networks...
option domain-name "elliot-labs.local";
option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.30, 8.8.8.8, 8.26.56.26, 8.8.4.4, 8.20.247.20;

default-lease-time 86400;
max-lease-time 86400;

# If this DHCP server is the official DHCP server for the local
# network, the authoritative directive should be uncommented.
authoritative;

# Use this to send dhcp log messages to a different log file (you also
# have to hack syslog.conf to complete the redirection).
log-facility local7;

# No service will be given on this subnet, but declaring it helps the 
# DHCP server to understand the network topology.

#subnet 10.152.187.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
#}

# This is a very basic subnet declaration.

#subnet 10.254.239.0 netmask 255.255.255.224 {
#  range 10.254.239.10 10.254.239.20;
#  option routers rtr-239-0-1.example.org, rtr-239-0-2.example.org;
#}

# This declaration allows BOOTP clients to get dynamic addresses,
# which we don't really recommend.

#subnet 10.254.239.32 netmask 255.255.255.224 {
#  range dynamic-bootp 10.254.239.40 10.254.239.60;
#  option broadcast-address 10.254.239.31;
#  option routers rtr-239-32-1.example.org;
#}

# Zoo of Death
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    server-name "Elliot-vDeploy";
    next-server 192.168.0.100;
    filename "boot\\x86\\wdsnbp.com\000";
    range 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.253;
    option routers 192.168.0.1;
    default-lease-time 86400;
    max-lease-time 86400;
    # Elliot-vWeb
    host Elliot-vWeb {
        hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
        fixed-address 192.168.0.40;
        }
    # Elliot-vADDS
    host Elliot-vADDS {
        hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
        fixed-address 192.168.0.30;
        }
    # HAOH-vWeb
    host HAOH-vWeb {
        hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
        fixed-address 192.168.0.35;
        }
    # Elliot-vNetworkOperations
    host Elliot-vNetworkOperations {
        hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
        fixed-address 192.168.0.15;
        }
    # Zoo-Printer
    host Zoo-Printer {
        hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
        fixed-address 192.168.0.4;
        }
    # Elliot-vMCc
    host Elliot-vMCc {
        hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
        fixed-address 192.168.0.55;
        }
    # Elliot-vMCs
    host Elliot-vMCs {
        hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
        fixed-address 192.168.0.50;
        }
    # Elliot-vDeploy
    host Elliot-vDeploy {
        fixed-address 192.168.0.100;
        hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
        }
    }
# A slightly different configuration for an internal subnet.
#subnet 10.5.5.0 netmask 255.255.255.224 {
#  range 10.5.5.26 10.5.5.30;
#  option domain-name-servers ns1.internal.example.org;
#  option domain-name "internal.example.org";
#  option routers 10.5.5.1;
#  option broadcast-address 10.5.5.31;
#  default-lease-time 600;
#  max-lease-time 7200;
#}

# Hosts which require special configuration options can be listed in
# host statements.   If no address is specified, the address will be
# allocated dynamically (if possible), but the host-specific information
# will still come from the host declaration.

#host passacaglia {
#  hardware ethernet 0:0:c0:5d:bd:95;
#  filename "vmunix.passacaglia";
#  server-name "toccata.fugue.com";
#}

# Fixed IP addresses can also be specified for hosts.   These addresses
# should not also be listed as being available for dynamic assignment.
# Hosts for which fixed IP addresses have been specified can boot using
# BOOTP or DHCP.   Hosts for which no fixed address is specified can only
# be booted with DHCP, unless there is an address range on the subnet
# to which a BOOTP client is connected which has the dynamic-bootp flag
# set.
#host fantasia {
#  hardware ethernet 08:00:07:26:c0:a5;
#  fixed-address fantasia.fugue.com;
#}

# You can declare a class of clients and then do address allocation
# based on that.   The example below shows a case where all clients
# in a certain class get addresses on the 10.17.224/24 subnet, and all
# other clients get addresses on the 10.0.29/24 subnet.

#class "foo" {
#  match if substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 4) = "SUNW";
#}

#shared-network 224-29 {
#  subnet 10.17.224.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
#    option routers rtr-224.example.org;
#  }
#  subnet 10.0.29.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
#    option routers rtr-29.example.org;
#  }
#  pool {
#    allow members of "foo";
#    range 10.17.224.10 10.17.224.250;
#  }
#  pool {
#    deny members of "foo";
#    range 10.0.29.10 10.0.29.230;
#  }
#}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look and see what is different from mine.